# Fancytree trigger load programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I am using [fancytree](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree) in my project and I want to trigger the lazy loading of a node programmatically and also want to add a callback. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to load a lazy node you can call [`node.load()`](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/FancytreeNode.html#load):

```
node.load().then(function() {
    // do something when children have loaded
})
```

Also, all load operations trigger the [`loadChildren`](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/global.html#FancytreeEvents) event:

```
loadChildren: function(event, data) {
    // data.node has new children now
},
```